# Loop array of object and insert into new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to create a new array of objects to avoid a nested array map. But I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscriber_data' of undefined
```

I've tired this:

```
let newdata = this.props.status
var newArr = newdata[0].subscriber_data.map(function(elem) {
    return {
        email: elem.email,
        name: elem.sub_name
    };
});
console.log (newArr)
```

Here is my JSON Structure:

```json
[
  {
    "subscriber_data": [
      {
        "sub_name": "User1",
        "email": "user1@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Result:** New array must be created with the objects inside

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, data structures, markup, etc. and such **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: But the error is pretty clear and specific: `newdata[0]` is `undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OK I will edit the question, and yes need help to fix the undefined error

Comment: The given structure is clearly not what `newdata` refers to. If it did, you wouldn't be getting the error you're getting.

Comment: clearly `this.props.status` is NOT the *JSON structure* you think it is ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I am passing the JSON data to my other component like this. `<LatestSubscribersNew status={this.state.dashboarddata} />`

Comment: right ... clearly `this.props.status` is NOT the *JSON structure* you think it is ...

Comment: Why don't you inspect the value of `newdata`? It is part of the debugging exercise a programmer would perform in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

could you convert the json back to an object that js would understand using

`const newData = JSON.parse(nameOftheJSONStructureHere)`

Comment: you mean to say like this `const newData = JSON.parse(this.props.status);` ??